# Get Unsupported Media Type when create custom model binder and use from query

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core

in asp.net core 3.1 i create custom model binder,and it's work fine.
in controller when i use FromQuery with complex model i get Unsupported Media Type.

controller and class:

```
    public class myModel
    {
        public myModel()
        {}
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    }


[HttpGet("project/list/GetData")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData([FromQuery]myModel model)
        {
          //some code
        }
```

startup code:

```
    services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;


                    IHttpRequestStreamReaderFactory readerFactory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHttpRequestStreamReaderFactory>();
                    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new DefaultsModelBinderProvider(options.InputFormatters, readerFactory));
                });
```

my BinderProvider class:

```
     public class DefaultsModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
        {
            private readonly IList<IInputFormatter> formatters;
            private readonly IHttpRequestStreamReaderFactory readerFactory;

            public DefaultsModelBinderProvider(IList<IInputFormatter> formatters, IHttpRequestStreamReaderFactory readerFactory)
            {
                this.formatters = formatters;
                this.readerFactory = readerFactory;
            }
            public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
            {

                if (context.Metadata.ModelType.BaseType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyRequest)))
                    return new DefaultsModelBinder(formatters, readerFactory);

                return null;
            }
```

and ModelBinder:

```
        public class DefaultsModelBinder : IModelBinder
        {
            private BodyModelBinder defaultBinder;

            public DefaultsModelBinder(IList<IInputFormatter> formatters, IHttpRequestStreamReaderFactory readerFactory)
            {
                defaultBinder = new BodyModelBinder(formatters, readerFactory);
            }

            public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
            {
                await defaultBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
                if (!bindingContext.Result.IsModelSet) return; //<= problem is here,and IsModelSet was false

            //some code
            }

        }
```

my response :

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "|a8d35c74-47e9398b95bd3d9f." 
}
```

I couldn't find the problem
What do you think is the problem and what should I do to solve this problem?
thank's for your help

Comment: What is your custom model binding used to do?Your action receive like:`[FromQuery]myModel model`.The name is `model`,so you just request the url like:`https://localhost:portNumber/project/list/GetData?model.ProjectId=1&model.OwnerId=2`.

Comment: @Rena,when i dont pass any querystring this problem still exists. according to the microsoft from this link learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/… BodyModelBinder binds models from the request body,so on this senario we should bind custom from httpcontext request queryString

Answer (score 0):

A 415 here means simply that the mime type of the request *body* doesn't have any applicable formatter in ASP.NET Core. For example, out of the box, you get this if you send XML as the XML formatters are not included by default. If you add them in, then the error goes away, because ASP.NET Core then knows how to handle the `application/xml` mimetype, namely via sending it over to an XML serializer to deserialize it into an object.

None of that is applicable to anything coming `FromQuery`. The query string doesn't have a mime type: it's just key-value pairs of strings. It's not clear how you're making the request or what the request actually looks like from the question, but to get this error, you're sending *something* in the body, and that *something* is off.

Comment: thank's for your answer, im just send request and get this error, Whether with querystring or without querystring .when i comment AddMvcOptions , and use default binder,everything works fine

Comment: finaly i found the propblem, according to the microsoft from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.binders.bodymodelbinder?view=aspnetcore-3.1 BodyModelBinder binds models from the request body,so on this senario we should bind custom from httpcontext request queryString